# Can IntPtr be cast into a byte array without doing a Marshal.Copy?

Tags: c#, .net, intptr

I want to get data from an IntPtr pointer into a byte array.  I can use the following code to do it:

```
IntPtr intPtr = GetBuff();
byte[] b = new byte[length];
Marshal.Copy(intPtr, b, 0, length);
```

But the above code forces a copy operation from IntPtr into the byte array. It is not a  good solution when the data in question is large.

Is there any way to cast an IntPtr to a byte array?  For example, would the following work:

`byte[] b = (byte[])intPtr`

This would eliminate the need for the copy operation.

Also: how can we determine the length of data pointed to by IntPtr?

Comment: You should definitely copy the data because the `IntPtr` points into *unmanaged memory*!

Comment: Thanks for your very quick reply, but that IntPtr was returned from C++ export function, so I can manage and delete it anywhere that I want. I don't want to copy the data because the data is video buffer, so its very large. Copying will make bad performance. Thank you!

Comment: That is really no reason to go for unsafe practices... you really should copy the content - there are several safe methods to do so  (some faster than others)...

Comment: @Yahia If the contract and lifetime is well-defined, I'm not sure what would make it "unsafe", excepting the keyword. (In both cases it's inherently "unsafe" memory access.)

Comment: @TTGroup An IntPtr (usually) represents an address. There is no notion of length: the length information must be transmitted separately. (Perhaps the first "int of memory" at IntPtr contains the length? Or perhaps just a separate [out] parameter.)

Comment: If performance is so crucial, do you want to move to managed code at all?

Comment: @zmbq: Can you guide me how to do it with your way? My main purpose is from C# can get the pointer that is returned from C++ functions. And C# will manipulate directly this data through the pointer address without copying the data. If your way can do it, please guide me. Many thanks!

Comment: You can do that with unsafe code, but it won't be any easier than doing it in C++. So just do it in C++.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there is no way you can store the data in a *managed* `byte[]` without copying (with the current structure you've provided*). However, if you don't actually *need* it to be in a managed buffer, you can use `unsafe` operations to work directly with the unmanaged memory. It really depends what you need to do with it.

All `byte[]` and other reference types are managed by the CLR Garbage Collector, and this is what is responsible for allocation of memory and deallocation when it is no longer used. The memory pointed to by the return of `GetBuffer` is a block of unmanaged memory allocated by the C++ code and (memory layout / implementation details aside) is essentially completely separate to your GC managed memory. Therefore, if you want to use a GC managed CLR type (`byte[]`) to contain all the data currently held within your unmanaged memory pointed to by your `IntPtr`, it needs to be moved (copied) into memory that the GC knows about. This can be done by `Marshal.Copy` or by a custom method using `unsafe` code or pinvoke or what have you.

However, it depends what you want to do with it. You've mentioned it's video data. If you want to apply some transform or filter to the data, you can probably do it directly on the unmanaged buffer. If you want to save the buffer to disk, you can probably do it directly on the unmanaged buffer.

On the topic of length, there is no way to know the length of an unmanaged memory buffer unless the function that allocated the buffer also tells you what the length is. This can be done in lots of ways, as commenters have mentioned (first field of the structure, out paramtere on the method).

*Finally, if you have control of the C++ code it might be possible to modify it so that it is not responsible for allocating the buffer it writes the data to, and instead is provided with a pointer to a preallocated buffer. You could then create a *managed* `byte[]` in C#, preallocated to the size required by your C++ code, and use the [`GCHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) type to pin it and provide the pointer to your C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation, I have used unsafe code to do it :)

Comment: I accounted with the same issue, and I want to save the content of the ‘IntPtr’ to file which opened by C#. You mentioned that it probably can be done, do you know how? Also, I’m using it in a UWP

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
byte* b = (byte*)intPtr;
```

Requires [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) (in the function signature, block, or compiler flag [`/unsafe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx)).

Comment: You should mention this requires the `unsafe` keyword in the function signature or within a pair of curly braces: `usafe { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried it. But the compiler threw the error when building "Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context". I don't understand this error, please explain to me. Thanks!

Comment: Your project needs to be configured to allow unsafe code, the code stated in the answer needs to be wrapped in unsafe (as @MikeBantegui said), and most importantly, this provides you with an unmanaged pointer to the unmanaged memory, not a CLR byte[] reference

Comment: @random65537 `fixed` is neither required nor possible here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a managed array occupy unmanaged memory. You can either copy the unmanaged data one chunk at a time, and process each chunk, or create an `UnmanagedArray` class that takes an `IntPtr` and provides an indexer which will still use Marshal.Copy for accessing the data.

As @Vinod has pointed out, you can do this with `unsafe` code. This will allow you to access the memory directly, using C-like pointers. However, you will need to marshal the data into managed memory before you call any unsafe .NET method, so you're pretty much limited to your own C-like code. I don't think you should bother with this at all, just write the code in C++.

Comment: Not even with "unsafe" stuff?

Comment: Ah, unsafe stuff. Yes, you can do that with unsafe stuff. Do you really want unsafe stuff?

Comment: Not sure, not my question :) But it would be interesting to see how this *could* be done, even if there are big warning flags.

Comment: If you make all the code that accesses this buffer unsafe, and do pointer arithmetics, you can pull this off. But it won't be any easier than simply doing the whole thing in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32125/Unmanaged-Arrays-in-C-No-Problem) page for a solution to working with unmanaged arrays.