# Casting a structure to a byte array in a clr project

Tags: c#, casting, c++-cli, clr

I have a function in c# to be called from a clr project. But the C# function paramter is byte[] and I am passing a strucutre in the function call in my clr project.

How do I cast this structure to a byte[] in clr?

In P1: (c# project)

```
void fun1(byte[] x) {...} //fun definition
```

In P2: (clr project)

```
fun(z); //function call
```

where z is a structure defined in P2. I have to cast z to byte[]

Comment: What is your structure that you pass?

Comment: I defined the structure and it just contains a couple of ints and a few byte arrays

Comment: please include code examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast an unmanaged structure to a managed byte array.  You'll have to copy:

See: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733059/495262

Comment: It can be either unmanaged or managed.  You didn't show us the code of the struct, so I had to guess.

Comment: The struct is either declared as `ref struct` (managed) or `struct` (unmanaged)

Comment: I read that you can use Marshal::Copy to convert that to a managed byte array and then use that byte array as a parameter for my function. But, Marshal::Copy takes an IntPtr as the first parameter. How do I make my unmanaged struct an IntPtr?

Comment: `MyStruct mystruct;
System::IntPtr myIntPtr(&mystruct);`